# ionic package build android FAILED due to TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic3

I just created a demo ionic project by `ionic start conference`, but when I tried to build the Android package, it tell me that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Then I tried to create another demo, `ionic start blank`, failed again.

`ionic serve` works all good and here is the information of `ionic info`

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.9.5
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Is there any dependency problem?

Comment: Obvious question..you  have added the android platform?

Comment: After added the command is able to run, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following command to build for android:

> ionic cordova build android